# Path - Android / PhoneGap

Tags: android, xml, cordova

am building an app that gets new data from a server - xml and images, and saves that to the sdcard. I then use either the xml from within the app or the one on the sdcard, downloaded from the server. This works fine... the trouble is the xml references images - and ones that were installed with the app work fine. 
I need to be able to use the new images, that were downloaded though. 
Right now I have the images like so in the xml:

```
<listImage>images/breakfast/thumb_zucchiniBread.jpg</listImage>
```

That for images installed with the app. When I get the new xml, and want to use images on the sdcard how can I do this? I've tried using the path the images are downloaded to like so:

```
<detailImage>data/data/com.gmr.humana/gallery_oats.jpg</detailImage>
```

But it doesn't work. Have tried Android/data etc...

This needs to work on iOS also, but hoping to just get Android working first.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get file/image from system local file storage 
function getFileSystem{
   window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail() {
    console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
   console.log("got filesystem");
   console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
   window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;   
}
```

Comment: Right, however the problem with that is that the images, from the xml, get used to build html. So the images just get put into an <img tag and the src attribute changed to the image's path in the xml. So, am hoping I can still just modify src attribute. Or is that not possible?